# RStudio document outline

Tags: rstudio, document, outline

I have tried using the document outline feature in RStudio, but it's not indenting the way I expected it to. I'm curious if there's a way to achieve the desired output.

Reproducible example below:

```
#A----
##a1----

##a2----
function1 <- function(){}

#B----
##b1----
function2 <- function(){}

##b2----
```

example shows:

```
A
 a1
 a2
  function1
  B
 b1
  function2
   b2
```

I would like the outline to look like this:

```
A
 a1
 a2
  function1
B
 b1
  function2
 b2
```

I am using RStudio 2023.06.0+421, R version 4.3.1 on Mac OS 12.6.
Could you please help me identify what I am doing incorrectly and provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I can produce your desired(correct) outline using your code in R 4.2.3 and RStudio 2023.06.0+421 on both macOS 12.6 and Windows 10 machines. The code seems correct.